# How to add a link into subject area of Gmail

Tags: html, email, smtp, html-email

I see an anchor link inside the e-mail subject! Searched some forums etc. but I couldn't find any information about how to do this.

Can anyone help?

[image: th]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Gmail and is known as AMP for Email. Read up about this on Google's website https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail (having said that, other email providers are working to support this)

A full writeup as to exactly 'how-to' for email is available on Email on Acid: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/industry-news/whats-the-latest-with-amp-and-how-can-i-use-it-for-email/